# What shelves to get for a china cabinet?

Tags: cabinets

I just purchased a somewhat old China cabinet. It has 2 heavy, thick glass shelved. One shelf is cracked so I plan to replace both shelves with painted wood shelves.

The width is 40 3/4 inches by 15 inches deep. The glass shelves are held in place by 4 metal pegs, 2 on each end.

Could someone tell me what material I should use for the shelves? I don't want the shelves to sag or collape.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for the responses! I was very concerned I would get the project done only to have the shelves sag or worse break. No more worries now. I am off to the store for wood. I plan to look at what is available, size, and cost. Tk folks! Helen

Answer (score 1):

Since you're painting anyway, it doesn't make much sense to use the more expensive hardwoods like quarter-sawn white oak or blistered maple - quite ordinary poplar should do very nicely unless you plan to put a huge amount of weight on those shelves. Poplar is strong and dense, and it paints exceptionally well.

Note that you'll need to edge-laminate two or more planks to get your full 15" depth if you use poplar.

Another entirely viable option would be to use 3/4" MDF. It comes in sheets (you can often buy half-sheets and quarter-sheets). It's very heavy (about 96 pounds per full sheet). It's also very rigid and dense and takes paint very well. So well, in fact, that it's sometimes used as an inexpensive siding on condos. It doesn't tolerate moisture, though, so be sure to fully paint all surfaces.

Comment: If it's going to get painted, what about 3/4" plywood? As long as you fill and sand the visible edge, nobody will ever know. No worries about having to laminate two planks together, it won't have the moisture problems of MDF, and it's cheaper than any hardwood.

Comment: I would also vote for plywood over MDF. It is possible that MDF could take on a permanent bow if it had a certain amount of weight on it.

Comment: According to the sagulator - http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/ - a 3/4" medium density MDF shelf would sag 0.48" with a uniform 100lb load across the shelf. On the other hand 3/4" fir plywood would sag only 0.14" with the same loading. For reference sake 1/2" thick glass would sag only 0.02" with that same 100lb uniform load. Since TDHofstetter recommended poplar the sagulator says that it would deflect 0.11" total.

Comment: I have yet to see any softwood plywood that didn't come with a sag or bow (or propellering) right off the stack. The same goes for the hardwood plywood you get from the BOB. Good-quality furniture-grade plywood typically comes flat, as does most Baltic Birch, but good non-BB plywood (even poplar-core ply) costs about a hundred dollars a sheet and nobody ever sells it in quarter-sheets or half-sheets. BB comes in odd sizes like 3'x5', and isn't anything like cheap. I - um - would hope that nobody would be putting a hundred pounds of "stuff" on a china-cabinet shelf...